# Upload a file using curl

Tags: curl, bitbucket-pipelines

How do I upload a file in bitbucket?

I am using the example found in step 3b

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads/

My updated command line.
curl -X POST "https://${BITBUCKET_USERNAME}:${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"Build-55.zip"

This will run in the directory that the zip file is located in.  Build-55.zip will be dynamic based on the build number.

I get an error message

> Warning: setting file Build-55.zip  failed!

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: It looks like you may be using Windows CMD curl.   If so, you need to find some  other way to run your curl.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you used Atlassian's own pipe for uploading artifcats

https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations??category=artifactmanagement&&p=atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file

```
pipelines:
  default:
    script:
      - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.3.3
        variables:
          BITBUCKET_USERNAME: ${BITBUCKET_USERNAME}
          BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: ${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}
          FILENAME: Build-55.zip
```